# Badly sized form issue (form cut off)

Tags: windows-7, resolution

I'm running Windows 7 with a screen resolution of 1980x1080. Occasionally I get forms from programs that appear to be cut off. Changing my screen resolution does not seem to solve the problem, and it's not unique to ReSharper (only shown in the picture as an example).

[image: ReSharper]

Does anyone have any idea what is causing this, and how to solve it? I ask as many times it is much worse than one button being a little obscured.

Comment: Have you increased the text size setting in `Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display`?

Comment: Nope. Its all standard (I mean that when I check there its says 125% (Default))

Comment: Interesting, my PC (with a 1680x1050 monitor) has 100% as the default. What happens if you try 100%?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your DPI to 100%.  This will correct the text size for your applications that are not adapting well to an unexpected DPI setting.

Comment: It worked thank you. Is there a way I can do it without changing the size of everything on my screen?

Comment: Unfortunately this is a system-wide setting for the currently logged-in user.  You might consider reporting this as a bug to the vendor (and feel free to link to this web page if that helps you save time in describing the problem).