# Windows 7/Outlook 2010 cut off controls on form windows

Tags: windows-7, display, microsoft-outlook-2010

I am running windows 7 with multiple monitors.  2 at 1920 x 1200 and 1 at 1600x900 resolution.  Controls are cut off and I cannot view the entire content of the window.

[image: cut off content]

As far as I can tell I only have the issue with Outlook 2010, it may be present in other applications but I haven't noticed it.  For example to get to the more settings button I have to use tab and then click enter.  The more settings button is never visible.  I have used applications that allow you to force windows to be resizable, however the anchoring is such that it remains cut off.

This has been present over multiple clean installs on the system.  My DPI is set to 100% unlike this [issue](https://superuser.com/questions/290388/badly-sized-form-issue-form-cut-off).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Odds are you are missing the "Tahoma" font.  Check your windows\fonts folder to see if it is there.

You can download the font from here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/188081

Comment: Wow. How in the world did you determine I was missing a font?  Easy, quick, and fixed. Thanks!

Comment: No freaking way! That's all it was? The Tahoma font got deleted from my system? I've lived with this issues for at least a couple years. @Bradley Uffner just made my day. Thank you from the future. I've lived with this annoyance in Outlook for at least 2 or 3 years but never in all my googling had I found a solution before. Clearly I need to work on my GoogleFu.